# Third order differential equation in python

Tags: python, ode

I am new to Python so that at this time, I can only very basic problems.

How do I solve an ODE like this in Python?

[image]

Comment: Use `scipy.integrate.odeint` or `scipy.integrate.ode`. Both python packages have nice tutorial pages. After doing that, add some code that you tried by editing the question. This then demonstrates how far you understood all this, then a sensible answer is possible.

Comment: " I can only very basic problems." I have to know: do you consider an ODE a "very basic problem" ?  If not then what kind of help are you expecting from us? and if yes then what on earth is a difficult problem to you?

Answer (score 2):

Your solution could look like this (if you remove all plot related lines, it is quite short)

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Qt4Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as pl

# define the ODE as a first order system
def func(y,x):
    return [ 
        y[1], 
        y[2], 
        ( 7*x**1.5 - 5*x**2*y[2]-2*x*y[1] + 2*y[0]) / x**3 
        ]    

# initial values
y0=[ 10.6, -3.6, 31.2]
# points at which the solution value is requested
x = np.linspace(1,10,501)
# numerical integration
y=odeint(func, y0, x)
# y[-1,:] contains the value at x=10
print "[ y(10), y'(10), y''(10) ] = ", y[-1,:]

# plot the solution with subplots for each component
fig=pl.figure()
ax=fig.add_subplot(311)
ax.plot(x, y[:,0])
ax=fig.add_subplot(312)
ax.plot(x, y[:,1])
ax=fig.add_subplot(313)
ax.plot(x, y[:,2])
pl.show()
```

Comment: Based on `def func()`, in the example it returns 3 values. Is that means y', y'', y'''? To be feed to change y, y', y''? So, the final result of odeint output is y, y', y''? If I also want to plot y''', is that possible?

Comment: There are implementations of solvers that record the vector field along the trajectory, the scipy ones do not have this. Here you would need to apply the ODE function to the trajectory points and extract the third derivative. It is possible that the vectorized call `dy = func(y.T,x)` works, then y''' is `dy[2]`.

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.ode.html

Here the library you are searching for, if you scroll down on the bottom there are some examples too. Have a nice reading